# URL is truncated by webbrowser.get

Tags: python, macos, google-chrome, url

I am using the following code to open a local web page.

```py
import webbrowser

url = "file:///Users/sm9449/Desktop/speedtest.html?direct=1"

chrome_path = 'open -a /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app %s'
webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open(url)
```

**PROBLEM**: the code below only passes the file path

```
file:///Users/sm9449/Desktop/speedtest.html
```

to Chrome, and drops the parameter

```
?direct=1
```

The url itself works fine if I just copy (CTRL-C) the URL directly into the chrome browser search field. I am using a Macbook with Mojave OS.

*Any help will be appreciated. thanks*

Comment: The `?direct=1` is a [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) and doesn't make sense within the context of a file URL. If the scheme of the URL was `https`, then the query is preserved in order to provide it to the web server. But not a file URL.

Comment: Or are you saying that you literally have a file name on your file system called `speedtest.html?direct=1`? If that were the case, then you'd have to percent escape the URL, e.g. `file:///Users/sm9449/Desktop/speedtest.html%3Fdirect=1`.

Comment: No, ?direct=1 is a switch for external urls. When used in the browser an alert box is automatically bypassed. Like I mentioned, if you copy paste the complete url ‘file:///Users...=1’ everything works. But webbrowser.get drops anything after html.